# Fix dns on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dns, ubuntu-16.04

I did something to mess up my DNS on my virtual ubuntu 16.04 box.  Can you help me diagnose what the problem is and get DNS working again.  I am able to connect to servers using an ip address.  However, when I use hostnames, my box can't resolve them.  This used to work - I did something to mess it up, but don't remember what file I edited.

ubuntu version:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Here's the problem using a hostname:

```
  root@ubuntu:/etc/dhcp# curl -vvv http://example.com
  * Rebuilt URL to: http://example.com/
  * Could not resolve host: example.com
  * Closing connection 0
  curl: (6) Could not resolve host: example.com
```

I can connect to example.com using an ip address.  I truncated the response because it's not relevant.  The point is that I am definitely connected to the internet.  My problem is that DNS is messed up.

```
curl -H "Host: example.com" "http://93.184.216.34"
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
```

Here's my dns server:

```
nmcli dev show | grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             172.16.217.2
```

Which seems to work:

```
dig @172.16.217.2 example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @172.16.217.2 example.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42927
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; MBZ: 0005 , udp: 1220
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        5   IN  A   93.184.216.34

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
example.com.        5   IN  TXT "ETPA"

;; Query time: 184 msec
;; SERVER: 172.16.217.2#53(172.16.217.2)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 09 14:45:02 EST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 84
```

My resolve.conf file might have a problem:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/dhcp# ls -latr /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Jan  5 12:21 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
root@ubuntu:/etc/dhcp# ls -latr /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
ls: cannot access '/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf': No such file or directory
```

The "host" command fails

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/dhcp# host -v -d example.com
Trying "example.com"
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

So, why won't curl or my browser or anything work with hostnames?  What should I do to diagnose and fix?

Comment: do you have to use your own DNS server or can you use, say, Google's? (8.8.8.8)

Comment: I tried adding 8.8.8.8 to my /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf.  It didn't fix anything.  "supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;"  And this command didn't reflect the google server: "nmcli dev show | grep DNS".  I'd like to use my own dns server because it can see things behind my company firewall.  However, google would be a step forward and may help diagnose the issue.

Comment: What is in your `/etc/resolve.conf`?  You can try  `host -d example.com` and the output will contain IP address of DNS server queried.

Comment: I added resolv.conf to the information in my question.  It's a symbolic link which points to a non-existent file.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg I also added "host" command output.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg You pointed me to the right answer.  After noticing that resolve.conf was messed up, I fixed it with this page: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1774632.  If you want to post an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I thought I had broken dns, but I didn't make this change.  Not sure why dns stopped working, but at least it's working now.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg I posted an answer, but I'm waiting to mark is as correct.   If you post an answer, I'll mark it correct.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your posted results follows that name server @ 172.16.217.2 works correctly, but it was not clear if it was used for address resolution.That's why I asked about `/etc/resolve.conf` that is the place where system looks for name server(s) to be used.
It looks like some `systemd` services broke this file (I have `/etc/resolv,conf -> /var/run/resove.conf` on Kubuntu 20.04).

Packages `resolveconf` and  `resolveconf-admin` may help do deal with such problems.

Answer (score 1):

This was the key problem; resolv.conf pointed to a non-existent file.

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/dhcp# ls -latr /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Jan  5 12:21 /etc/resolv.conf ->   /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
root@ubuntu:/etc/dhcp# ls -latr /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
ls: cannot access '/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf': No such file or  directory
```

The fix was to point it to an existing file:

```
ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```